# Mongo Connection Pool issue in Spring Boot

Tags: mongodb

I am using Spring Boot application with Mongo Data.
From cron scheduler calling 1 method.So the method is getting called in a loop.For each call 1 new mongo connection getting opened when interacting with DB.

> 2017-11-14 06:22:40.994  INFO 15196 --- [http-nio-8060-exec-13]
>   org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection
>   [connectionId{localValue:32, serverValue:505}] to localhost:27017

After some connection opened (around 100 connections) new connection not getting opened and getting MongoTimeOutExceptions.

I am using MongoRepository for mongo connection.

1. Is there any way to handle connection pool in spring boot application using mongo DB?
2. Is there efficient way to close the used connection in application level?

Comment: Could you post the code showing how the connection is created and used please?